# Html element not taking up its full width with absolute positioning and inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This gray block (https://jsfiddle.net/var6u4g7/) on the right doesn't take up the full width of it's content. It's using the size of the `righttext`, if you add more words in the `righttext` element you'll see the grey box is taking up exactly that width. I don't want to assign a fixed width because I don't know how much will be inside it, so I want it to be as wide as its content.

If you remove `display: flex` on the first element then the width works but other things break. (If you remove the grey box you'll see why I need `display: flex`. The grey box only appears sometimes, and when it's not there all the content in that row should be vertically center aligned. Is there a way to make this work?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.leftside {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.rightside {
  position: relative;
}

.righttext {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftside">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <div class="righttext">
      Lorem ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="absolute">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The right side is taking up the width of its content. `righttext ` is the content that is inside of `rightside` and it is taking exactly that width. Your absolute div is positioned absolutely and is not in the content flow so it will not determine the width of its parent (`rightside`)

Comment: So I can't force the absolute div to take up as much space as it needs? The `righttext` will be smaller than the absolute div so it'll always have this problem.

Comment: Unless you set a width to it or move it out of `rightside`. I am not sure what exactly you need to achieve but there are probably other ways to do whatever it is you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from the question exactly what you are looking for, but if I do understand correctly, you want the red and gray boxes to be full-width. You can do this by adding `flex: 1` to `.rightside` and `width: 100%;` to `.absolute`. The `flex` property indicates that a certain element should take priority. It's shorthand for `flex-grow: 1`.